# How can I prevent proguard from keeping some of my method names

Tags: android, proguard

I have been testing my apk against an online apk decompiler and I've noticed that some of my method names are there in clear text.

For example on one of my activities I have a suspend method called `mySuspendMethod' and this is what I will find when the code is decompiled:

```
@C0463c(mo2892c = "mypackage.MyActivity$mySuspendMethod$2", mo2893f = "MyActivity.kt", mo2894l = {304}, mo2895m = "invokeSuspend")
    /* renamed from: mypackage.MyActivity$j */
    /* compiled from: MyActivity.kt */
    static final class C2963j extends w02 implements rb0<C5499yq, C0328iq<? super Boolean>, Object> {
```

`MyActivity` has to have an exclusion with `-keep class` because it is an `Activity` but I still want most of the methods to be totally obfuscated.

I only have this on `keepattributes`:

`-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature`

I also have this, can't remember why:

`-repackageclasses ''`

Any idea how to prevent that type of stuff from showing up when decompiling the apk?

Edit: I think this is where the decompiler is getting it from (this is from the `smali` file.

```
.annotation runtime Lkotlin/coroutines/jvm/internal/c;
    c = "mypackage.MyActivity$mySuspendMethod$2"
    f = "MyActivity.kt"
    l = {
        0x136
    }
    m = "invokeSuspend"
.end annotation
```

Edit: using the `whyareyoukeeping` I got the explanation but it doesn't make a ton of sense:

```
mypackage.MyActivity
|- is referenced in keep rule:
|  /Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4de4b1c7915434eb501f4eea74700a11/transformed/jetified-ads-sdk-3.9.0.3/proguard.txt:44:1
java.lang.Object mypackage.MyActivity.mySuspendMethod(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
|- is invoked from:
|  java.lang.Object mypackage.MyActivity.access$mySuspendMethod(mypackage.MyActivity,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
|- is invoked from:
|  java.lang.Object mypackage.MyActivity$anotherMethodOnMyActivity$1.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object)
|- is overriding method:
|  java.lang.Object kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.invokeSuspend(java.lang.Object)
|- is referenced in keep rule:
|  /Users/me/somepath/app/proguard-rules.pro:108:1
```

The line that proguard file is pointing to is:

```
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
```

I don't remember why I have that line but I'm guessing it is needed. I don't know why it has to do with any of this though. Could it be that it is referencing the wrong rule? If I look at line `108` of the final `configuration.txt` file I see `-dontnote android.net.http.**`. Seems as unlikely to be at fault as the other one.

Comment: May I have your ProGuard file/configuration to take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard has an option `-whyareyoukeeping` which will output some explanation for why it can't shrink something. Check out the documentation at https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage

To check a specific method, use something like this in your proguard file:

```
-whyareyoukeeping class mypackage.MyActivity* {
  int myMethodName(...);
}
```

See the full syntax definition here: https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification

Comment: Any idea how I would use that for a specific method? I only see examples for classes.

Comment: See above edit. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I've added that and got the explanation though it doesn't make much sense. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute MyApplication
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
-keep class mypackage.MyActivity { 
            private void !mySuspendMethod(); 
// NOTE: you have to change private, void and the parameters in () to your mySuspendMethod signature
}
```

`!` negates the method, so everything outside of the method will be kept.
Do make sure that the method signature is followed exactly if not this won't work.

If it does not work, feel free to leave a comment and I check the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It won't work like that. Only way I could get it to accept the signature was `private ** mySuspendMethod(**);` but then it doesn't accept the `!`.